# Google Play Services Authentication Popup not closing

Tags: android, react-native, google-play-services

The prompt to sign in and authenticate using a Google account won't go away. I am calling the prompt to be opened, so that part works, however, when I select my account, the prompt just closes and reopens.

When my app is in development mode, I can authenticate with no issues. However, when in my release environment, this is when the error occurs.

[image]

Comment: Are you using a [release key](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html) ?

Comment: Oh, no I'm not. I'll be sure to look at that. Thanks!